# how to rewrite HTML code of all active ebay items description

Tags: ebay-api

i have 1800 active ebay items need to revise. these 1800 HTML files( item description part ) have already rewrite at my local computer. how can we revise HTML code(not text) of all these items' descriptions with our New HTML code.

or how can we revise an active ebay item description' HTML code(not text) by ebay API ?

sorry for asking such simple question because i am pretty new for ebay api :)

thanks a lot :)))

MSRDeveloper

Answer (score 1):

With the eBay api use **GetSellerList** to get all items.

Then change all item descriptions with the call **ReviseFixedPriceItem**.

Don't forget to put the description in a **CDATA** block!

### Python example for changing all http in description to https:

```
def revise_fixed_price_item_html(self, item):
    if "http:" in item["Description"]:
        description = item["Description"].replace("http:", "https:")
        settings = {"Item":
            {"ItemID" : item["ItemID"],
             "Description" : "<![CDATA[{0}]]>".format(description)}
            }
        api = Trading(config_file=self.config_file)
        response = api.execute("ReviseFixedPriceItem", settings)
```

You can also take a look at **DescriptionReviseMode** (see links below)

#### Links:

https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetSellerList.html
https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/ReviseFixedPriceItem.html

https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/ReviseFixedPriceItem.html#Request.Item.Description
https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/ReviseFixedPriceItem.html#Request.Item.DescriptionReviseMode

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on that same sort of problem for a couple of months now.  I came up with using Excel and VBA to send a request to get all active selling ItemID's.  Then, you can use getItem calls for each item number to get the old html description if you need that.  I was removing the html that Vendio and several other trials had added so I did need the old html to manipulate programmatically.  Last, you can write a macro to send back whatever new html you want to put in new.  The only inputs you need are ItemID and html description.